# Limit content inside the div by its size

Tags: php, css, html

I'm dynamically filling a table of content fetch from the database.
This table is inside a `<div>`

So I'm setting a variable `$col` to limit how much columns I want each row `(by default I saw 5 fit perfectly) in the div`. Otherwise the table content just goes outside the div.

The problem is I had to set that manually. I looked around a lot how to make any content inside div and 
 once it colides with the border but couldn't find anything. If I could have the same result without using tables which are the problem I think . I'll be glad to update that.

```
$col = 1; //initialisation

foreach ($result as $product){ //a loop to fetch data into product object
if($product->visible == 1){
    if($Col < 6){
   echo "<td>";
   echo "<a href ='read.php?id=".$product->id_product."&p=0'><div class='productdiv'>";
   echo "<img src ='galleries/".$product->id_product."/c".$product->id_product.".jpg' alt = 'cover' width='220' height='300'><h4 class='productclass'>".$product->name_product."</h4>";
   echo "</div></a>";
   echo "</td>";
   $col= $col+ 1; //here I'm incrementing
   }
  else{ //I close the line <tr> then another line begin
echo "</tr><tr><td>";
echo "<a href ='read.php?id=".$product->id_hentai."&p=0'><div class='hendiv'>";
 echo "<img src ='galleries/".$product->id_product."/c".$product->id_product.".jpg' alt = 'cover' width='220' height='300'><h4 class='productclass'>".$product->name_product."</h4>";
   echo "</div></a>";
   echo "</td>";
   $col= 1;
}//end the code
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUdQF.png)

Comment: what you want ?

Comment: fetch the data from your database and limit the results using  limit 5 that will work.

Comment: I want to accomodate the div of each product one by side of one but of course not trespassing the main div they're inside see the 'result' picture I've attached

Comment: @dean that's the problem. what if I want to make next a responsive website if they resize the content then only 2 each row for example shall be there.

Comment: hahaha, @GantzisGoat before the limit use a rand() selection with your query. for sure your query will select a random of 2 results at every page reload.  every results will be shown at a random of 2 , even if you have 1000+ results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use

```
display: inline-block
```

It will accommodate the content. And where you have open the `<tr>` in "`if`" condition.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll try this now

Comment: it works. And I just took it off when organizing the code I guess of course it's still there

Answer (score 0):

Not fully sure I understood your question but this sounds like a job for JS

1 You should read all possible columns from db and create table from them but set visibility to hidden.

2 Then add JS and define column priorities.

3 Get maximum allowed width for table.

4 Using JS read width of all you cells

5 By priority sum your cell width until it's > max width

6 hide cells with lesser priority that can't fit